# how to retrieve DTS Global variable value into Stored Procedure in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000, dts

I have created a DTS which inserts values of a text file into database table. I called DTS from stored procedure. I want to retrieve a value or a flag after inserting the data into database table, which shows values are successfully inserted.

Is their any way to retrieve a flag value from DTS to stored procedure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you have SQL table log in order to DTS package log errors on it. after each execute of DTS package check your table log, and if don't exists any error means convert data complete successful.

Comment: Thanks mehdi..
But I want to pass a variable from DTS to stored procedure..
Is it possible..???